# Why did Flutter SDK stop working suddenly?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I've been using Flutter for almost 6 months now. Tonight out of nowhere, VS Code said "Flutter SDK Not Found". It has a locate SDK option which I clicked and navigated to `C:/src/flutter`. I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzrc2.png) (on the bottom right).
I also tried `flutter doctor` in Powershell. This returns this error: 'flutter is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' even though the Flutter environment variable path is set.

Comment: It looks like your flutter sdk has been either moved, deleted, corrupted or removed from the PATH. I would reinstall and make sure your path variables match.

Comment: @EliFront yes i fixed it by deleting the old SDK and downloading a new one. Works fine now Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right flutter latest versions are not working for me too so i downloaded 1.22.2 stable version that worked for me.

Comment: Yes i fixed by downloading the latest flutter version thanks